# Making rules refresh page when message after one has time to read the message?

Tags: rules, javascript

Issue: 
I added a message that should be displayed upon user login using rules. It worked fine only that
 1. The page stuck (showing the message) and you had to refresh and click okay to discarding information upon reload.
 2. The page did refresh but did so immediately so that one did not have more than a split-second to view the message.

Question:
How do you make rules display the system for, say, 5 seconds and then refresh the page? A mixture between the two possible scenarios described above.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider

[Absolute Messages](https://drupal.org/project/absolute_messages)

> Displays system messages in fully themeable colored horizontal bars on
>   top of the page.
>   ...
>   * messages could be dismissed automatically after a specific time - configurable in module settings for each message type separately,